# Прописная или строчная буква в слове «божественный»?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, семантика, прописная-строчная, прилагательные

Скажите, пожалуйста, с прописной или со строчной буквы пишется слово "Божественный", когда оно употреблено не по отношению к единому Богу, а к целому пантеону богов или одному из нескольких богов?
Например: Божественная сила жителей Олимпа, Божественная мощь Зевса и пр. Или божественная?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из орфографического словаря: ***б**ожественный* (к божество; изумительный) и ***Б**ожественный* (к Бог, Божество; Божественная литургия).

Из толкового словаря:
[бог](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3)
**2.** *чего, какой*. При политеизме: одно из сверхъестественных существ, управляющих какой-либо частью мирового целого, покровительствующих кому-либо, чему-либо (обычно какому-либо роду деятельности). *Языческие боги. Боги Олимпа. Посейдон — **б**ог морей. Гефест — **б**ог огня и кузнечного ремесла. Марс — **б**ог войны.*

Прилагательное "божественный" по отношению к этим богам пишется со строчной буквы.

> — Волчий вой и обилие белок — к войне и пленению.
> — Не сули нам горе!
> — Не я сулю, а **божественная сила**.
> — Твои боги — Перун и Мокошь. Скажи им, чтобы они мне сокровища открыли.
> А. П. Ладинский. Последний путь Владимира Мономаха

> Но выступает Аполлон, и от него лучится такое **божественное**, грозное **величие**, что невозможно представить себе его в положении Ареса или Артемиды.
> <...>
> На прекрасном молодом лице — печать огромной силы воли. Стройное, мускулистое тело полно **божественной мощи**.
> В. В. Вересаев. Аполлон и Дионис

Answer (score 2):

В Словаре «Прописная-строчная», представляющем собой краткий свод основных выражений православной церковной лексики, сказано следующее:

> Имена Божии, Божией Матери и относящиеся к ним местоимения и
> определения пишутся с прописной буквы...
>
> Бог Господь, Единый Бог, Господь-Вседержитель, "Творец небу и земли".
> "Отче наш; Иже еси на небесех..." Господь наш Иисус Христос, Сын
> Божий, "Единородный, Иже от Отца рожденный". Дух Святой — "Царю
> Небесный, Утешителю, Душе истины, Иже везде сый..." Пресвятая
> Богородица, Дева Мария, "Благодатная Мария", "Благаго Царя Благая
> Мати", Пречистая и Преблагословенная, "Невесто Неневестная". Пресвятая
> Троица: "...благодарю Тя, Святая Троице".
>
> С прописной буквы пишутся также существительные и прилагательные,
> употребляющиеся в значении существительных, при именовании Господа и
> Матери Божией, некоторые прилагательные при именовании Господа и
> Матери Божией: Истинный Бог; Пресвятая Богородица.

https://lib.pravmir.ru/library/readbook/125?ysclid=l753d1yi8o496678606#sel=

С прописной пишется всё, относящееся к Богу, исходящее от Бога (Божественная литургия, Божественное Слово).

Со строчной — почтительные эпитеты (божественная благодать, божественная вечность).